# Compiling/Linking multiple c++ libraries in linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++, static-libraries

I have 3 separate libraries with no dependencies, exclusive to themselves, individually compiled using g++ -c and then individually added to separate archives using `ar rvs *.o`.

I now have 3 separate archives.

I now have another 4th library that depends on all 3 of the previous libraries. How can I compile my 4th library to include the 3 other exclusive libraries, to use all 4(referencing only the 4th library) in a main.cpp program?

I am a g++/linux/makefile COMPLETE BEGINNER.

Comment: Put those object files in the compile command for your 4th library.
`g++ -c lib4.cpp lib1.o lib2.o lib3.o`
then to compile main with all 4 use
`g++ main.cpp lib1.o lib2.o lib3.o lib4.o`

Comment: *"[then] ... added to separate archives using `ar rvs *.o`..."* - Be sure to run `ranlib` on the archive to generate the index.

Comment: I thought the s option creates the index?

Answer (score 3):

Is the fourth library a *static* library or a *dynamic* library?

The three first libraries are static libraries, they are nothing more than archives of object files. If the fourth library is that, then there's nothing you do with it, just create the archive.

The problem is when *linking* with the fourth library. Since static libraries are nothing more than archives of object files, you nee to link with *all four* libraries. You also need to put the libraries correct on the command line for the linker: If library A depends on library B, then A needs to come *before* B on the linker command line.

*On the other hand* if the fourth library is a shared library, then it is linked much like an executable program, and when doing that you link with all libraries needed as usual. Then when creating a program using the shared library, you don't need to link with the dependencies.

---

As for actual command line, the simplest way is to just add the libraries when linking:

```
$ g++ main.o -o my_program lib4.a lib3.a lib2.a lib1.a
```

The above command is for linking with static libraries, and after creating an object file of the `main.cpp` source.